# EditText style is different between different devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I wrote a android program on Android 4.0.3.  I deployed it to Samsung S3 (Android 4.1), S4 (Android 4.2.2), Note 2 (Android 4.1) and Google Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.4).  The edit text style is correct (I doesn't override any style in style.xml).  But in some devices the edit text style is different.

[image: Correct style in S4]

[image: In correct style in other device]

I don't know why all device's is Android 4.x but the style is different.
Please tell how to make it consistent!!!

Comment: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: you should use a common backgroud, if you need to make same in all devices

Comment: To the question, why? Well usually Samsung an others companies implements their own default style.

Answer (score 0):

it's based on your application theme. Define your app theme in AndroidManifest.xml, after your editbox view won't change.

try this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

then apply your style in your style.xml file :

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
<item name="android:textColor">#848484</item>
</style>
```